# RDWeb Icons not displaying properly

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop

I have created a remote app program using RDWeb and I can access the program correctly, however the icon is the default Remote Desktop icon and not the .ico file I linked the program to.

I have added several other programs which all work fine and display the correct icons, they come from the same directory.

I was wondering what could cause this issue, some other forums have suggested RDWEB access group not having write permissions on the C:\Windows\web\RDWeb\Pages\rdp, although checking through the local user manager, this group does not exist.

Is this an issue with resolution or permissions?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is experiencing the same issue I have found an answer.

For whatever reason RDWeb was resolving to the default PNG image (mstsc25632x32),this is located in the C:\Windows\Web\RDWeb\Pages\rdp directory.

Removing this allowed my RemoteApp to reference the correct icon and display properly.